# How to send internet of things (IoT) data to both a database and an SQS queue on Amazon Web Services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have industrial internet of things (IIoT) data coming from machines out in the wilderness. Currently the data are going from the machines to an Amazon Web Services (AWS) Simple Queueing Service (SQS) queue, for consumption by a third-party company.

I want to do two things now:

1. Put the data into the SQS queues for the third-party company, as before, and
2. Store the data in an Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS) database for analysis purposes

To accomplish this, should I send the data to an Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS) topic first, and then push the data from there to both my database, and an SQS queue for the third-party company?

Is there a better way of accomplishing my objective, or am I on the right track?

I ask partly because it seems that Amazon is steering me toward a noSQL database called DynamoDB, but I think I want a structured relational database for my IIoT data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon’s IoT “message broker”, which communicates with my IoT devices using MQTT, ***is an SNS topic***, which makes a lot of sense.

SNS message topics are different than SQS queues. Queues can only be read by one user, and then the message(s) get deleted from the queue—it’s just temporary storage. So we couldn’t share an SQS queue with the third-party company.

SNS topics, by contrast, send push notifications (and the messages) to multiple users instantly, and all “subscribed” users get the message(s). SNS is exactly like subscribing someone’s Twitter or Instagram feed, where all “subscribers” get notified of new messages from “publishers” to the message “topic”.

Long story short, we can use AWS IoT “rules” to send our devices' MQTT-secured “messages” to as many “subscribers” or AWS services as we want. So we’ll send one copy to the SQS queues, and another copy to an AWS database of some sort.